# How to use list filter on ssh2-sftp-client

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ssh2-sftp-client

I'm not quite sure how to use the filter on the list method of ssh2-sftp-client, my objective was to only list files which include a certain string.

The npm page is not particularly helpful on this.

```
          let data = await sftp.list(
            'engine/',
            (name: string) => !name.includes('READ')
          );
```

This returns an error, saying that includes is not a function.

Any guidance you guys could provide would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Got it,

```
      let data = await sftp.list('engine/', function (item: any) {
        return !item.name.includes('READ');
      });
```

Was waiting for a string, when it was an array of objects.

Thanks!